# DB2 function creates Locks

Tags: db2

I have created a DB2 user defined function.The function creates locks and the entire db2 studio hangs on creation and shows the -904 message. DB2 had to be brought down and restarted.

```
CREATE FUNCTION LOOP_FN (CUSTOM_DIVISION_GROUP VARCHAR(255), COMPANY VARCHAR(255), LOCATION VARCHAR(255),COMD VARCHAR(255),BASIS VARCHAR(1)) 
     RETURNS VARCHAR(30)

BEGIN
    DECLARE COUNT_VAR INT;
    DECLARE j int;
    DECLARE NAMES_VAR varchar(30);
    DECLARE myTemp varchar(30);
    DECLARE CustomGroup varchar(30);

    SET CustomGroup = '';   
    SET j = 0;
    SET COUNT_VAR = LENGTH(CUSTOM_DIVISION_GROUP)-LENGTH(REPLACE(CUSTOM_DIVISION_GROUP,',',''));

    IF BASIS = 'N' THEN

    WHILE j <= COUNT_VAR DO

    SET NAMES_VAR = (SELECT VALUE_1 FROM TABLE(SPLIT_PARAMS(CUSTOM_DIVISION_GROUP,',',COUNT_VAR+2)) WHERE ID_1=j+1);
    IF (LOCATE(':', NAMES_VAR)>0) THEN 
    SET myTemp = SUBSTR(NAMES_VAR,1,LOCATE(':', NAMES_VAR)-1); 
    ELSE 
    SET myTemp = NAMES_VAR;
    END IF;

    IF LOCATE(COMPANY||LOCATION,NAMES_VAR) > 0 THEN
    SET CustomGroup = myTemp;
    END IF;
    SET j = j + 1;
    END WHILE;

    ELSEIF BASIS = 'Y' THEN
    WHILE j <= COUNT_VAR DO
    SET NAMES_VAR = (SELECT VALUE_1 FROM TABLE(SPLIT_PARAMS(CUSTOM_DIVISION_GROUP,',',COUNT_VAR+2)) WHERE ID_1=j+1);
    IF NAMES_VAR = COMPANY||LOCATION||COMD||'Y' THEN
    SET CustomGroup = 'True';
    END IF;
    IF NAMES_VAR = COMPANY||LOCATION||COMD||'N' THEN
    SET CustomGroup = 'False';
    END IF;
    SET j = j + 1;
    END WHILE;

    END IF;
    RETURN  CustomGroup;
END@
```

Can anyone please help me resolve the issue and create the function. May I know what statements in the function cause this issue.

Comment: Your procedure has several conceptual errors in it, never mind whatever's causing the 904.  For one, you set `CustomGroup` to a value in the loop... but this will be overwritten during the next cycle.  The procedure is also doing two things (whatever the name bit comes out to versus `'True'`/`'False'` ... of which the latter is text, no less); you should really have two different procedures.  I'm highly suspicious of the fact that `Custom_Division_Group` seems to be a delimited list.  What version/platform of DB2, and what's the exact error message.

Comment: The function has been called as follows:   MISDB2A.LOOP_FN('PROCESSING: 16MAR 4520','90','202','','N')  The version of db2 used is DB2 for z/OS V10.

Comment: ... yeah, that looks even worse.  From the look of it, some of those parameters should be broken up.  `LOOP` is a terrible name for a function (and appending `FN` to designate it as a function is rather pointless.  (Alas, array parameters only became available in version 11 of z/OS, but...) - you don't need a loop at all - you should be able to do the comparison inside a regular statement.  The example you've provided returns an empty string, was that intended?